# Apply styling with pseudoclass :focus-visible on PrimeNG Components

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG Components like Checkboxes, Radiobuttons etc. in my application.

I want to apply CSS on these components, but only, when they are focused by pressing Tab and want to use the pseudo class :focus-visible.

I was able to apply CSS with something like

```
body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-active.ui-state-focus {
  border-color: red
}
```

But then style applies also, when focused by mouse click as well.

What would be the CSS syntax with :focus-visible pseudo class to style PrimeNG Components?

Comment: As far as I know, browsers do not differentiate between 'focus by tab' and 'focus by click'. It's just either 'focus' or 'no-focus'. More info: https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/#:~:text=For%20keyboard%20users%20%E2%8C%A8%EF%B8%8F%2C%20focusing%20on%20an%20element%20is%20very%20similar%20to%20hovering%20over%20it%20for%20mouse%20users.%20I%20like%20to%20think%20of%20the%20%3Afocus%20pseudo%2Dclass%20as%20a%20hover%20state%20for%20keyboard%20devices%2C%20because%20it%20signals%20a%20similar%20intention%20for%20interaction.

Comment: i think its a quite new browser feature, to differentiate between focused by click or tab https://bharathvaj.me/blog/focus-vs-within-vs-visible#:~:text=This%20selector%20is%20mostly%20useful%20to%20provide%20a%20different%20focus%20indicator%20based%20on%20the%20user%E2%80%99s%20input%20modality%20(mouse%20vs.%20keyboard).

Comment: Ah, then I suggest you make two different .css classes, one for `:focus` and one for `focus-visible`. And remove all visual styling related to `:focus`.

Comment: this is the question. i am not able to style PrimeNG Components with the pseudo class

Comment: Well, as far as I can find in their github, they haven't written anything to support this. https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/search?q=%3Afocus-visible  They have written a lot regarding :focus  (Check out focusTrap) but I found no references to :focus-visible